# ProcessStartInfo got error and won't work on IIS / Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, iis

I've found a code snippet from http://codebetter.com/brendantompkins/2004/05/13/run-a-bat-file-from-asp-net/ which one runs a bat file from ASP.NET code. It works in Visual Studio, however I couldn't run it at server. Screenshot is below:

[image: Screenshot]

And the code:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
psi.UseShellExecute = false; 
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

Detailed errors:

[image]

What would be wrong here?

The code below has also got the error:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // This line won't compile
```

Comment: I've copied the lines from Visual Studio. It looks like ProcessStartInfo has no properties.

Comment: Ok got it, the code needs to be in a function definition, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

My bad! The line below has been erased:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
```